# C# XML Structure Fix

Tags: c#, xml

I am attempting to convert an example XML "object" into something that I can then "**Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Classes**" into Visual Studio 2017.

The example XML I have been given looks like this:

```
<order><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns="http://tempuri.org/OrderXMLSchema.xsd">
<Header>
<customerNumber>######</customerNumber>
<customerPoNumber>MyPO1234</customerPoNumber>
<shippingBranch>##</shippingBranch>
<shipViaMethod>UPS Ground - Commercial</shipViaMethod>
<shipTo>
  <name>Test Pools</name>
  <addressLine1>2132 Delaware Ave</addressLine1>
  <addressLine2></addressLine2>
  <addressLine3></addressLine3>
  <city>Kenner</city>
  <state>LA</state>
  <postalCode>70062</postalCode>
  <shippingInstructions></shippingInstructions>
</shipTo>
<shipToNumber></ shipToNumber >
<contact>Jane Doe</contact>
<phoneNumber>555-555-5555</phoneNumber>
<faxNumber>555-555-5555</faxNumber>
<emailAddress>jane.doe@email.com</emailAddress>
<writtenBy>CIT</writtenBy>
</Header>
<OrderDetail lineNumber="1">
<productNumber>HAY-10-371</productNumber>
<quantity>2</quantity>
<comment>Line item comments</comment>
</OrderDetail>
<OrderDetail lineNumber="2">
<productNumber>HAY-10-372</productNumber>
<quantity>5</quantity>
<comment>Line item comments</comment>
</OrderDetail>
</Order>]]></order>
```

In the document at the bottom is a comment which I cannot seem to implement and get valid XML.

It says:

> *”[CDATA” and “]” may need to be removed for C# integrations, but may be needed for PHP integrations.

I just cannot seem to get valid XML and create it as a class in VS.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This XML is `<order>Text</order>`. If you want the structure, use the contents of CDATA as your XML.

Comment: The net library only accepts the ident tag "<?xml" as the first character in the xml and will reject the xml if it ident is not at the beginning of the steam.  So you need to remove the leading and trailing characters from the data.  You can use Regex to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
<Order xmlns="http://tempuri.org/OrderXMLSchema.xsd">
<Header>
<customerNumber>######</customerNumber>
<customerPoNumber>MyPO1234</customerPoNumber>
<shippingBranch>##</shippingBranch>
<shipViaMethod>UPS Ground - Commercial</shipViaMethod>
<shipTo>
<name>Test Pools</name>
<addressLine1>2132 Delaware Ave</addressLine1>
<addressLine2></addressLine2>
<addressLine3></addressLine3>
<city>Kenner</city>
<state>LA</state>
<postalCode>70062</postalCode>
<shippingInstructions></shippingInstructions>
</shipTo>
<shipToNumber></shipToNumber>
<contact>Jane Doe</contact>
<phoneNumber>555-555-5555</phoneNumber>
<faxNumber>555-555-5555</faxNumber>
<emailAddress>jane.doe@email.com</emailAddress>
<writtenBy>CIT</writtenBy>
</Header>
<OrderDetail lineNumber="1">
<productNumber>HAY-10-371</productNumber>
<quantity>2</quantity>
<comment>Line item comments</comment>
</OrderDetail>
<OrderDetail lineNumber="2">
<productNumber>HAY-10-372</productNumber>
<quantity>5</quantity>
<comment>Line item comments</comment>
</OrderDetail>
</Order>
```

Comment: The problem is that you have an XML document within an XML document.

Comment: @CodeCaster : This is a terrible response.  The XML is fine, just is doesn't work well with the ReadXml method because of the number of levels of the xml.  So a different XML library need to be used to parse the file.

Comment: @jdweng no, that is not a terrible response, it is the truth. The problem is not the "levels of the XML", that itself is a terrible response. The problem is that it is an XML document that, within its root node (`<order>...</order>`), contains an entire XML document in a `<![CDATA[...]]>` section, meaning that inner part is not XML, but just text. You may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML.

Comment: Look at the OP second Answer.  He already took out the CDATA.  Try taking the xml posted and use ReadXml.  You will see the number of tables create are useless.  The data become fragmented and cannot be put back together is a usable format.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not really sure what you're talking about or why you talk about ReadXml. The `<order></order>` root node the OP shows only contains text, and that text happens to have the form of an XML document. If they want to parse the latter, they first have to parse and obtain the text of the former. In this answer (the first and only answer here), they have copied the XML document and removed the spacing around `</shipToNumber>`, making the XML viable to be used for Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes.